# Does it make performance diffence if I use `touch` event instead of `click' event in JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I came to this question while I was reading an article to improve the performance of mobile apps.

[**ARTICLE**](http://www.speedawarenessmonth.com/15-things-for-making-your-site-faster-for-mobile-users/)

To cut short your precious time . I am pointing out the related point number there it 14.

This point says that we should change all the `click` event to `touch` event because `click` event takes half a second to fire in mobile device.

I am still rookie to Jquery/JQm . so I have a confusion .

that is click event is already supported in `Jquery Mobile` does that means this click event works differently than the normal `JS/Jquery` click event??(internally ) .

Or should I change all the click event from my `JQM` app to `touch` ?? .That will give me better performance .

I know I might be silly to ask this but I am really confused about this .

Would be really thankful if some one can suggest me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `click` event and the `touch` event are two different things. For most mobile devices, the click event fires after 300ms. The `touch` event fires as soon as a finger touches the screen.

For different ways of getting rid of that 300ms delay with the `click` event, see this article:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away

To make things easier for you though, jQuery Mobile includes a `vclick` event, which responds to both click and touch events. If you want your events to work on both desktop and mobile, use that. More info on `vclick` here:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/

Comment: yes i m using `vclick` event for my function . I am aware of this event thanks for the links though . And clarifying this was my actual confusion . Now I understood that `vclick` already optimized for `touch`

Answer (score 1):

It will be good to use `touch` if your potential users are mostly touch phone users. Also, it surely affects processing time, because a Mobile Operating system for touch phones have `touch` attributes and functions everywhere (just they are altered for `click` events). So, I would prefer `touch`.

Comment: Thanks @Ashwin for the answer . But I think Jan made it more clear to me about it :)

Comment: @Vikram Yeah sure...for me too.